# How to get current page for php/mysql pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I created a simple php/mysql pagination and I'd like to get current page to set the class `active` . The answers I found around here do not necessarily represents the kind of pagination I have created which is very basic.

pagination

```
<?php
//pagination
$perpage=403;
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page=$_GET['page'];
}
else{
        $page=1;
}  
$offset=($page-1)*$perpage;

$sqlu="SELECT * FROM ve_users u 
ORDER BY IsOnline DESC";
$resultu=mysqli_query($db,$sqlu);
$total_rows=mysqli_num_rows($resultu);
$total_pages=ceil($total_rows/$perpage);

echo"<div class='paginations'>";
echo "<a href='users.php?page=1'>&laquo;</a>";
for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){
echo "<a class='' href='users.php?page=$i'>$i</a>";
}
echo "<a href='users.php?page=$total_pages'>&raquo;</a>";
echo"</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$page` is where you capture the current page, so you have to change the pagination links' code block in the following way,

```
// your code
echo "<a href='users.php?page=1'>&laquo;</a>";
for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){
    if($i == $page){
        echo "<a class='active' href='users.php?page=$i'>$i</a>";
    }else{
        echo "<a href='users.php?page=$i'>$i</a>";
    }
}
echo "<a href='users.php?page=$total_pages'>&raquo;</a>";
// your code
```

Comment: @SebastianFarham You're welcome! Glad I could help. :-)